# Loop on two lists simultaneously

Tags: linux, shell

I am a beginner in linux and I want to do loop on two lists simultaneously. I have written a line of script and  I want to pick up names in the same order from each list and put it in my script.
here is example of my list and script

```
array=(A1 A2 A3)
array=(B1 B2 B3)
....../l2gen  ifile= ..../A.hdf   Geofile= ..../B.hdf  ofile=...../A_lc
```

Comment: I don't understand your `....`/`......` notation. Can you show an example of what the command would be if you couldn't use a loop? (For example, can you show what the command using `A1` and `B1` would be?)

Comment: those are just directory addresses. What I want is something like this

Comment: Those are just the directories address. I am using SeaDas software to do batch process for bunch of images. So, I have the list of the images and I want to replace A and B by the names of images. Each time I want to say replace A and B by A1 and B1, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
A_array=(A1 A2 A3)
B_array=(B1 B2 B3)

for (( i = 0; i < ${A_array[@]}; ++i )) ; do
    A="${A_array[i]}"
    B="${B_array[i]}"

    ....../l2gen  ifile= ..../"$A".hdf   Geofile= ..../"$B".hdf  ofile=...../"$A"_lc
done
```